# Какое тут средство выразительности?

Tags: тропы

"Долг, к сожалению, платежом красен". Какой здесь использован прием выразительности? И в "Зачем пришивать кобыле хвост". И ещё в "Под лежачий капитал инвестиции не текут".

Answer (score 2):

Есть такое понятие  "окказионально преобразованные фразеологизмы".  Другое явление - авторское преобразование фразеологизмов. У вас, похоже, второе.

Answer (score 1):

1.Фразеологизм на основе использования устаревшего слова "красен".- вводное слово не входит в структуру фразеологизма и не нарушает его, это немодифицированный фразеологизм. Остальные два - модифицированные. Это не тропы(семантический приём), а стилистический приём ДЕФРАЗЕОЛОГИЗАЦИИ.

Приемы дефразеологизации:
Экспликация внутренней формы (образной основы) фразеологической единицы.
Буквализация значения фразеологической единицы.
Двойная актуализация.
Фразеологическая контаминация.
Фразеологический эллипсис.
Расширение как способ интенсификации значений фразеологической единицы.
Обыгрывание структурно-семантической модели фразеологической единицы.
Замена компонентов фразеологической единицы словом или сочетанием слов.

2."Зачем пришивать кобыле хвост?". -дефразеологизация на основе синтаксической трансформации-повествовательное предложение превратили в вопросительное.

3."Под лежачий капитал инвестиции не текут".- дефразеологизация на основе структурной трансформации с заменой компонентов.

Comment: Дефразеологизация означает разрушение закрытой структуры фразеологизма.

Comment: (НЕ) ПРИШЕЙ КОБЫЛЕ ХВОСТ. — Да ты никак с ума сошёл? — удивлялась Прасковья Ивановна. — Теперь-то я мужняя жена, а тогда пришей хвост кобыле. Приказчики засмеют (Мамин-Сибиряк.

Comment: И что? Предложение-то повествовательное, это форма повелительного наклонения в самом фразеологизме, по значению равном сказуемому "лишняя"(неуместная, чужая).

Answer (score 0):

Да, Екатерина права, это похоже на  окказиональное преобразование фразеологизма, в частности на сегментацию.

Сегментация фразеологизмов – это разделение устойчивого выражения на части (сегменты), вычленение какой-либо части и использование ее в качестве самостоятельной синтаксической единицы в предложении.

Сегментация  фразеологизма является стилистическим средством выразительности (существует три вида средств выразительности: фонетические, лексические и синтаксические).

http://vestnik.yspu.org/releases/2011_3g/39.pdf

Comment: Здесь нет сегментации, используется не часть(сегмент)фразеологизма, а полностью, но в модифицированном виде.

Comment: Сегментация в двух других примерах. А здесь просто вставка, но суть от этого не меняется. Это окказиональное преобразование фразеологизма как стилистический прием выразительности.

Comment: Суть как раз меняется, в первом примере структура фразеологизма не изменилась, здесь только отношение автора к нему.Какое же это окказиональное преобразование?  в двух других - современный стилистический приём дефразеологизации, которым вовсю пользуются СМИ.Окказиональное не преобразование, а сам фразеологизм.Модифицированные фразеологизмы все окказиональные.